# Load Items in Advance in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using Recyclerview to load contacts in my android app. Each row has a contact number Textview and a username Textview. Contacts load from local database but usernames should load from remote server. I have tried loading usernames for each contact in `onBindViewHolder` method but its get stuck whenever I scroll fast.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactsAdapter.ContactsViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final ContactInfo current = cDataset.get(position);

             //Here I load from remote server...

   }
```

So I want to load usernames in advance while scrolling like Endless recyclerview. Is it possible to implement this?

Comment: First load contact from database then get username from the server then update your RecyclerView

Comment: I am doing the same thing, Loading contact from database first and trying to get associated username in onbindviewholder method. Are you telling to load all the usernames before loading recyclerview ?

Comment: don't implement server related calls in OnBindViewHolder Do it out side your adapter

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I got exactly what you are saying, but it seems like you want to load all data before loading it to your recyclerView.

instead of loading from remote server on onBindViewHolder, you can load it in advance either in your Activity or Fragment and pass it to your adapter...

Comment: No I dont want to load all data before loading into the recyclerview at once. Example if the screan can show 5 items, I want to load next 5 items in advance. So whenever we scroll next 5 items are ready to show up.

Comment: I see what you mean now, you still probably want to load all data in advance and use endless scroll.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqJAKA5IEF8 this is what you want right?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the get call in your onBindViewHolder, you should already have your data by now.

Either obtain your data via a call prior to initializing your Adapter or if you still need to get the data from inside the Adapter, put that call within a background thread, though you are likely to run into problems there as well if you scroll fast.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you load items in chunks of size of 30. Add `OnScrollListener` on your `RecyclerView`. Every time you pass some threshold, for example, 20 out of 30 items, you initiate fetching the next chunk of 30 items, and, once you have them, put them at the and of the `RecyclerView`.

Play with this numbers. Instead of 30 and 20, you may try 100 and 50, or 50 and 10. Find numbers for which you have the best UX. However, do not count that user will always have prepared next set of data, so keep one circular `ProgressBar` at the end of `RecyclerView` as long as you have more data to load.

Another approach which you may try is to periodically start a service that will fetch all required data, prepare everything the way it is required for UI, and cache it in memory or in DB.